# How to split audio from different instances of Firefox (or another) browser to separate sound cards

Tags: firefox, flash, audio, streaming

I would like to be able to separate the audio being played by Flash Media Player when there are two tabs playing different streams in Firefox (or another browser).

Frustratingly, Adobe Flash Player doesnt offer any choice of the sound card to route to (it always chooses the windows default) and different instances of Flash players all route the audio to the same 1 instance of Flash Player in Windows Audio config.

I have tried a few ideas without success: running two completely separate instances of Firefox, installing Safari to see if it’s possible to configure the FlashToHTML5 extension (WebKit2webprocess.exe). Multiple instances of Firefox use the same Flash player as mentioned, and the FlashToHtml5 plugin works nicely but again it doesn’t seem to be possible to run instances for each tab or change the sound card.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions to try.

Windows 7 64 Bit.

Comment: yeah, good luck, I would say just get two cheap PCs, but the next best thing would be virtualization?

Comment: I'll give it a try with virtual box. Also, I just read that Windows Explorer creates separate instances of  flash so will investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it some more, a VM may really be your best bet. I looked into it, and sure enough, Virtual box SHOULD let you send audio from one card and then to another from a another VM. Give it a shot.

[image]

Comment: Looks interesting. At the moment Im pursuing the IE option as I have discovered that IE does in fact create separate instances of the IE program in the Audio devices panel in W7 audio options and if I can find a program to take the audio stream out of each instance to its own sound card then im golden. I think I saw a prog like that sometime.  This is preferable to a Virtual Box because of the obvious resource drain from using multiple boxes. I imagine it would be quite a lot of CPU and memory for each instance

Comment: Well, like I said, best of luck, don't forget Win7x86 only needs one GB of RAM.

Comment: IM using 64 bit, how does it compare?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is using x64 for the Host OS and x86 for the guest OS

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and after a lot of searching and even considering buying a second computer, I ended up with setting up a Virtual Machine using VMware-player and installed Ubuntu.

There may be neater or better ways to do this, especially if you have limited RAM, btut this may work for now.